# how to include llvm library in c++ project

Tags: c++, cmake, llvm

**I am trying to build a lifter where I have written my code in c++ and now I am trying to include LLVM in my project. I have written my CMakeLists.txt for my lifter project as follows**:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13.4)
project(lifter)

find_package(LLVM REQUIRED CONFIG)

message(STATUS "Found LLVM ${LLVM_PACKAGE_VERSION}")
message(STATUS "Using LLVMConfig.cmake in: ${LLVM_DIR}")

# Set your project compile flags.
# E.g. if using the C++ header files
# you will need to enable C++11 support
# for your compiler.

include_directories(${LLVM_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_definitions(${LLVM_DEFINITIONS})

# Now build our tools
add_executable(lifter main.cpp BB.cpp Func.cpp Register.cpp Immediate.cpp Instr.cpp Utilities.cpp OpCode.cpp)

# Find the libraries that correspond to the LLVM components
# that we wish to use
llvm_map_components_to_libnames(llvm_libs support core irreader)

# Link against LLVM libraries
target_link_libraries(lifter ${llvm_libs})
```

**I have also included the llvm header files that I want to use in my project**

```
#include "llvm/IR/Value.h"

#include <llvm/Pass.h>

#include <llvm/ADT/SmallVector.h>

#include <llvm/IR/BasicBlock.h>

#include <llvm/IR/CallingConv.h>

#include <llvm/IR/Constants.h>

#include <llvm/IR/DerivedTypes.h>

#include <llvm/IR/Function.h>

#include <llvm/IR/GlobalVariable.h>

#include <llvm/IR/InlineAsm.h>

#include <llvm/IR/Instructions.h>

#include <llvm/IR/LLVMContext.h>

#include <llvm/IR/Module.h>

#include <llvm/Support/FormattedStream.h>

#include <llvm/Support/MathExtras.h>

#include <llvm/IR/IRBuilder.h>

#include <algorithm>

#include "llvm/IR/PassManager.h"

#include "llvm/IR/CallingConv.h"

#include "llvm/IR/Verifier.h"

#include "llvm/Support/raw_ostream.h"

using namespace llvm;
```

**when I use this command inside the directory of my project:**

```
cmake -H. -Bbuild
```

**I get this output:**

```
- Found LLVM 13.0.0
-- Using LLVMConfig.cmake in: /usr/lib/llvm-13/cmake
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/hany/lifter_master_thesis_final/build
```

**then when I use the next command:**

```
cmake --build build -- -j3
```

**I get this output:**

```
[ 33%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/lifter.dir/Func.cpp.o
[ 33%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/lifter.dir/main.cpp.o
[ 33%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/lifter.dir/BB.cpp.o
In file included from /home/hany/lifter_master_thesis_final/Func.h:2,
                 from /home/hany/lifter_master_thesis_final/Utilities.h:14,
                 from /home/hany/lifter_master_thesis_final/main.cpp:1:
/home/hany/lifter_master_thesis_final/Register.h:13:2: error: ‘Value’ does not name a type
   13 |  Value* register_value;
      |  ^~~~~
/home/hany/lifter_master_thesis_final/Register.h:17:33: error: ‘Value’ has not been declared
   17 |  Register(std::string reg_name, Value* reg_value);
      |                                 ^~~~~
/home/hany/lifter_master_thesis_final/Register.h:23:2: error: ‘Value’ does not name a type
   23 |  Value*  get_register_value();
      |  ^~~~~
/home/hany/lifter_master_thesis_final/Register.h:29:20: error: ‘Value’ has not been declared
   29 |  void insert_value(Value* value);
      |                    ^~~~~
In file included from /home/hany/lifter_master_thesis_final/Func.h:2,
                 from /home/hany/lifter_master_thesis_final/Utilities.h:14,
                 from /home/hany/lifter_master_thesis_final/Func.cpp:1:
/home/hany/lifter_master_thesis_final/Register.h:13:2: error: ‘Value’ does not name a type
   13 |  Value* register_value;
      |  ^~~~~
/home/hany/lifter_master_thesis_final/Register.h:17:33: error: ‘Value’ has not been declared
   17 |  Register(std::string reg_name, Value* reg_value);
      |                                 ^~~~~
In file included from /home/hany/lifter_master_thesis_final/Func.h:3,
                 from /home/hany/lifter_master_thesis_final/Utilities.h:14,
                 from /home/hany/lifter_master_thesis_final/main.cpp:1:
/home/hany/lifter_master_thesis_final/Immediate.h:12:2: error: ‘Value’ does not name a type
   12 |  Value* immediate_value;
      |  ^~~~~
/home/hany/lifter_master_thesis_final/Register.h:23:2: error: ‘Value’ does not name a type
   23 |  Value*  get_register_value();
      |  ^~~~~
/home/hany/lifter_master_thesis_final/Register.h:29:20: error: ‘Value’ has not been declared
   29 |  void insert_value(Value* value);
      |                    ^~~~~
/home/hany/lifter_master_thesis_final/Immediate.h:24:2: error: ‘Value’ does not name a type
   24 |  Value* get_immediate_value_long();
      |  ^~~~~
In file included from /home/hany/lifter_master_thesis_final/Func.h:3,
                 from /home/hany/lifter_master_thesis_final/Utilities.h:14,
                 from /home/hany/lifter_master_thesis_final/Func.cpp:1:
/home/hany/lifter_master_thesis_final/Immediate.h:12:2: error: ‘Value’ does not name a type
   12 |  Value* immediate_value;
      |  ^~~~~
/home/hany/lifter_master_thesis_final/Immediate.h:24:2: error: ‘Value’ does not name a type
   24 |  Value* get_immediate_value_long();
      |  ^~~~~
In file included from /home/hany/lifter_master_thesis_final/Func.h:2,
                 from /home/hany/lifter_master_thesis_final/Utilities.h:14,
                 from /home/hany/lifter_master_thesis_final/BB.cpp:1:
/home/hany/lifter_master_thesis_final/Register.h:13:2: error: ‘Value’ does not name a type
   13 |  Value* register_value;
      |  ^~~~~
/home/hany/lifter_master_thesis_final/Register.h:17:33: error: ‘Value’ has not been declared
   17 |  Register(std::string reg_name, Value* reg_value);
      |                                 ^~~~~
/home/hany/lifter_master_thesis_final/Register.h:23:2: error: ‘Value’ does not name a type
   23 |  Value*  get_register_value();
      |  ^~~~~
/home/hany/lifter_master_thesis_final/Register.h:29:20: error: ‘Value’ has not been declared
   29 |  void insert_value(Value* value);
      |                    ^~~~~
In file included from /home/hany/lifter_master_thesis_final/Func.h:3,
                 from /home/hany/lifter_master_thesis_final/Utilities.h:14,
                 from /home/hany/lifter_master_thesis_final/BB.cpp:1:
/home/hany/lifter_master_thesis_final/Immediate.h:12:2: error: ‘Value’ does not name a type
   12 |  Value* immediate_value;
      |  ^~~~~
/home/hany/lifter_master_thesis_final/Immediate.h:24:2: error: ‘Value’ does not name a type
   24 |  Value* get_immediate_value_long();
      |  ^~~~~
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/lifter.dir/build.make:63: CMakeFiles/lifter.dir/main.cpp.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/lifter.dir/build.make:89: CMakeFiles/lifter.dir/Func.cpp.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/lifter.dir/build.make:76: CMakeFiles/lifter.dir/BB.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:79: CMakeFiles/lifter.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:84: all] Error 2
```

my question is how come llvm classes(llvm:Value or llvm::Instruction for example) arent recognized as I am building my project when I have already included the header files and included llvm in my CMakeLists.txt while in visual studio code I don't get any errors regarding those classes being undefined.

I am new to using llvm and using CMakeLists.txt to include external libraries in my project :).. what could I be doing wrong here, please.

Comment: Don't use the undocumented `-H` flag. The documented equivalent is `-S`.

Comment: @drescherjm, why do you say that..is it obvious in the error message?

Comment: The errors do not seem to be related to the CMake. It seems more likely a problem in the code. And I mean one or more of your files is not including the header that defines Value.

Comment: `Func.h` uses `Value` but it's not defined. It is provided by `llvm/IR/Value.h`. Func.h should probably include the llvm header as well. `using namespace` in headers is discouraged, would it be too much pain to rewrite `Value` to `llvm::Value`?

Comment: @AlexReinking i used  cmake -S. -Bbuild after deleting previous build folder but still same issue.

Comment: Cosmetic issue: your llvm header `#includes` can't decide whether they're `""` (local header) or `<>` (system header), pick one style and stick with it.

Comment: It probably should use `<>` as these should not be local to your code.

Comment: @dratenik, I followed your advice and it worked perfectly :)..thank you